# I am using warbler gem for creating war file for my ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, tomcat6, warbler

War file is successfully created.But when i deploy and run the app,following exception is thrown.

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:866)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:829)
    at RUBY.(root)(D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:14)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054)
    at RUBY.(root)(jar:file:/D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.7.4-lib-jruby-stdlib-1.7.4.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1)
    at RUBY.require(jar:file:/D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.7.4-lib-jruby-stdlib-1.7.4.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054)
    at RUBY.(root)(D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:6)
    at RUBY.(root)(jar:file:/D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.7.4-lib-jruby-stdlib-1.7.4.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1)
    at RUBY.require(jar:file:/D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-jars-1.7.4-lib-jruby-stdlib-1.7.4.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/D:/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/RORCouponDemo/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.13.2-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment3.rb:23)
```

I have configured jruby path in environment.My app is using ruby v-1.9 and not jruby.